# F# applying universally typed mapping

Tags: f#, functional-programming

I'm struggling with finding out why this code below doesn't work.

Let's say I defined a function Map (like List.Map) for universal type.

```
type Uni = Iu of int
            | Flu of float
            | Su of string
            | Bu of bool
            | Lu of Uni List
            | Fu of (Uni -> Uni)

let uMap : Uni -> Uni -> Uni =
    fun (Fu f) (Lu xs) -> Lu (List.map f xs)
```

That works fine, now I'm trying to call that function but my code doesn't seem to match with the function signature.

```
uMap (Fu(fun (Iu(x)) -> Iu(x) + Iu(1))) (Lu([Iu(2); Iu(3); Iu(4)]))
```

The error is to be from the function applied for mapping (the first argument), more specifically, from the `Iu(1)` within `(Fu(fun (Iu(x)) -> Iu(x) + Iu(1)))`

> error FS0584: Successive patterns should be separated by spaces or
>   tupled

How should I use this function? I can't seem to find any problem with it.

Comment: You don't need `c#` tag for this question. Removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you actually wanted

```
uMap (Fu(fun (Iu(x)) -> Iu(x + 1))) (Lu([Iu(2); Iu(3); Iu(4)]));;
```

A few of your brackets were in the wrong place and I think you used `Iu(x) an Iu(1)` in places where you meant `x` and `1` respectively.